# Google places API using fragments

Tags: android, google-places-api

When I click on add order it will open the fragment named as create order fragment

```
<fragment 
    android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"  
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment">
```

and in create order fragment i have created google places api 
when i click again to the add order it gives me an exception like.

[image]

**There are two links for that images**

[image: Image 3]

[image: Image 1]

Comment: Please add some codes, especially your xml file code

Comment: Edit your question, don't post code in comments